# Using function name by variable in pl/sql

Tags: function, plsql

I am working on PL/SQL code, My purpose is to declare function with definition then assign it to variable then call it using that variable.

```
 declare
 func varchar2(50);
 function add(a NUMBER,b NUMBER)
 return BOOLEAN is
 c NUMBER; 
 begin
 c := a+b;
 dbms_output.put_line(c);
 end add;
 begin
 func :='add'; or func :=add;
 if (func(10,20)=false) then
     dbms_output.put_line('false statement');
 else
    dbms_output.put_line('true statement');
 end if;
end;
```

But this is not working. So I am not getting how to assign function to variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build an anonymous block with the function call you need and then call it with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. You should know how many arguments the function has though.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE
  func VARCHAR2(20);
  value1 NUMBER := 10;
  value2 NUMBER := 20;
  plsql_block VARCHAR2(500);
  out_value NUMBER;  
BEGIN
  func := 'add';

  plsql_block := 'BEGIN  :v := ' || func || '(:v1,:v2); END;';      

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block USING OUT out_value, IN value1, value2;

 IF out_value > 0 THEN
   dbms_output.put_line('TRUE statement');
 ELSE
   dbms_output.put_line('FALSE statement');
 END IF;
END;
```